# Chrome not completely deleting indexedDB database

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, indexeddb

I've been trying to close and delete an indexedDB database, but I'd say about 10% of the time it gets stuck in a less than desirable state. What happens is it will delete all of the object stores, but leave the database entry as you can see in the screenshot below.

[image]

The goal is to completely delete the indexedDB database in one fell swoop when the user logs out and then reload the page. When the database isn't completely deleted it can cause issues when the user logs in as `onupgradeneeded` isn't called and the object stores aren't recreated.

```
this.db.close();

var request = indexedDB.deleteDatabase("mcfarljwtest2");

request.onsuccess = function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        location.reload(true);
    }, 1000);
};

request.onerror = function(error) {
    console.log(error);
};
```

Is there something I'm missing or overlooking here to get it to completely delete 100% of the time?

Comment: Try naming your question more specifically, maybe it will help. Like "Chrome not completely deleting database?".  Also, can you recreate this error in another browser, or just Chrome?

Comment: Right now it appears to only be happening in Chrome (36/37).

Comment: Provide a full, self-contained demo and report it at http://crbug.com/new

Comment: Did you notuce it happen only when the app is running on other tab?

Comment: @RobW I'll have to make a bug report for it when I have time.

Comment: @KyawTun, I'll have to keep an eye out for that one, but I don't think I have multiple instances open.

Comment: It happen only when dev console open?

Comment: try using the jquery indexedDB plugin. it will require code changes but provides better implementation of indexedDB
see
http://nparashuram.com/jquery-indexeddb/

Comment: @KyawTun I have only noticed it when the dev console is open, but our error logs using raygun would suggest it's happening occasionally to users who likely don't have the console open.

Comment: @user3260861 While we don't be switching to that plugin. Thanks for bringing it up because I can look at how it handles deleting the database.

Comment: This sounds like it could be a dev console integration issue; I suspect what is happening is that the console enumerates the databases, your code runs to delete the database, then the console opens the database to inspect the contents, implicitly recreating the database at v1. https://crbug.com/539931

Answer (score 2):

You've found a bug in Chrome!

I filed this as https://crbug.com/539931 and just landed a fix. Barring any unexpected side effects, the fix should be in Chrome 48.

As you noted above, it's specific to having devtools open and actively inspecting the database resources, so it is unlikely to affect end-users, just developers.